# Android USB debugging with PC internet connection

Tags: android, debugging, usb

I'm having Samsung Galaxy S phone.

I want to debug my application, which needs internet connection.

can I debug my app with android device, sharing the PC internet connection through USB?

I can not use WiFi.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: doesn't your phone have a 3G connectivity of its own?

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/9441879/779408

Answer (score 3):

Getting the internet from your PC to your android device is called reverse tethering. It is tricky cause it s not a built in feature. Some solutions exist if your a linux user :

http://blog.mycila.com/2010/06/reverse-usb-tethering-with-android-22.html

**Previous link is dead, found a copy there:**

https://web.archive.org/web/20120320173806/http://blog.mycila.com/2010/06/reverse-usb-tethering-with-android-22.html

Don't know if it's still relevant the question is old considering Android lifetime.

If you are not, well I never find a way.

Comment: Wonderful, very useful for debugging released builds connecting to local server.

Answer (score 2):

There are two current (2019) tools that do this job well:

#### [gnirehtet](https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet)

> This project provides reverse tethering over adb for Android: it allows devices to use the internet connection of the computer they are plugged on. It does not require any root access (neither on the device nor on the computer). It works on GNU/Linux, Windows and Mac OS.

It's written in Rust and Java; you can choose the server component. It requires `adb` on the host, and at least Android 5.0. The device itself will then be managed by the program.

#### [SimpleRT](https://github.com/vvviperrr/SimpleRT)

> Reverse Tethering utility for Android.
>
> Allows you to share your computer's internet connection with your Android device via a USB cable

This one requires no `adb` and no rooting, but you have to build the Android APK file yourself or [download a release version](https://github.com/vvviperrr/SimpleRT/releases).

Comment: SimpleRT is amazing, but sadly only works on Linux-based distros at the moment.